# Java/JS/TS Given row and column get bit value in truthtable

Tags: javascript, java, typescript, bit

Is their a short formula for calculating the bit value for a given row and column?
Example: getTTBit(row = 3, col = 2) = 1

4 2 1
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 0
0 **1** 1  <-- row 3, col 2 -> 1
1 0 0
1 0 1
1 1 0
1 1 1

It should be as quick as possible. I dont want to convert the row number into a bitarray and get the col'th element because I work with large numbers (rows). My bad current solution looks like this (TS):

```
export function getTTBit(numCols: number, row: number, col: number): bit {
    return getNumberAsBitArray(row, numCols)[col];
}

export function getNumberAsBitArray(n: number, length: number): bit[] {
    return [...Array(length)].map((_, i) => n >> i & 1).reverse() as bit[];
}
```

Comment: Java is to JavaScript as ham is to hamster.

Comment: I know both languages well. So i dont care for a specific solution for either of them.

Comment: Then please be more clear on _exactly what you need_. Are we expecting a string input, binary digits, a multi-dimensional array, or what? What is the expected result? Besides that, please be extra-clear when you tag a question with multiple languages: "A solution in _either_ Java or JavaScript/TypeScript".

Comment: As you can see above row and col are numbers. A function getTTBit() with given arguments row = 3 and col = 2 should return 1.

Comment: If you know both languages well what code have you worked on yourself to try and solve the problem? You should add that to the question as well as deciding what specific language you want people here to respond with.

Comment: Added my current solutions that I dont like

Comment: @Andy As I said I dont care if your solution is in Java, TS or JS

Comment: I don't understand your example. Why this row is row 3 while this col is col2. I get that "4 2 1" is header. But even ignoring header, the row you designated is the 4th one. Which is logical. In all languages you've mentioned indexation starts at 0, so row 3 is the 4th. But same should go for columns. How come it is the 2nd column (so col 1) that is bold? Is this just a format error? (after all, 3rd column, aka col2 is also 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically, you're asking how to check if the Nth bit is set in a number?

This is the same in all three languages:

```
isSet = (row & (1 << col)) != 0
```

where `col` is counted from the right (lsb=0).

Comment: I see. And if col is from the left? If i add numCols (bitsize of the number) argument I get the right answer:
return (row & (1 << numCols - 1 - col)) != 0 ? 1 : 0;
How to change your solution so that numCols is obsolet?

Comment: @Oli: to get  the bit length of a number you'd need something like `Math.floor(Math.log2(x))` in javascript, no idea about java.

Comment: Thank you for your answer . I think i will go with this: 
return (row & (1 << numCols - 1 - col)) != 0 ? 1 : 0;